# WhiteSpace with Boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I need to search a string with whitespace using Boost:regex search, but it never matches.

I need to get the username from the work mail (second match in the input below), but the order can change, so I need to scan the whole string.

**Input:**

homemail: mail:username@mail.com
workmail: mail:username@mail.com

**Regex:**

```
workmail: mail:\s*([^@>;]*)
```

In pcre it works correctly: http://regex101.com/r/uD4pH7/1

In Boost, I've tried a lot of ways like:

```
workmail: mail:\s*([^@>;]*)

workmail:\\smail:\s*([^@>;]*)

workmail:\\x20mail:\s*([^@>;]*)

\\Qworkmail: mail:\\E\s*([^@>;]*)

workmail:[[:space:]]mail:\s*([^@>;]*)

workmail:[[:s:]]mail:\s*([^@>;]*)
```

My boost lib version is 1.42.0 installed via apt in Debian 6 system.
I'm using the boost::regex_search function.

Comment: So where is the issue?

Comment: Work in boost 1.54, probably a bug already fixed. Update boost. Tested the first one you try.

Comment: The issue is that in boost the regex never matches because the whitespace.

Comment: Upgraded to Boost 1.56 and the result is the same, it doesn't match anything. @NetVipeC you tested this one **workmail: mail:\s*([^@>;]*)** and it worked ?

Comment: @NetVipeC can you please send me the example code that you tested ?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting: `#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main() {
 std::string s = "homemail: mail:username@mail.com workmail: mail:username@mail.com";
 boost::smatch m;
 if (boost::regex_search(s, m, boost::regex("workmail: mail:\s*([^@>;]*)"), boost::match_default | boost::match_partial)) {
  std::cout << "** Match found **\n   Sub-Expressions:\n";
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i)
   std::cout << "      $" << i << " = \"" << m[i] << "\"\n";
 }
 return 0;
}`

Comment: Thank you @NetVipeC. The upgrade to the new lib version really worked, and all of the regex that I proposed in the main post works. Thank you for your attention. +1 for you!